# Mysql delete by primary key with select(error 1093)

Tags: mysql, select, primary-key, sql-delete, mysql-error-1093

I want to delete a record from mysql by primary key,that is account_recharge_detail_id.
when i use the following scripts,that works:
SELECT account_recharge_detail_id FROM account_recharge_detail where operator_name='fanny-test';  (it returns 101)
DELETE from account_recharge_detail where account_recharge_detail_id=101;

but when i join the two together:
DELETE FROM account_recharge_detail where account_recharge_detail_id in (
SELECT  A.account_recharge_detail_id FROM 
account_recharge_detail as A where A.operator_name='fanny-test')

it returns :Error Code: 1093. You can't specify target table 'account_recharge_detail' for update in FROM clause

I want to make it works in one sentence,How can I solve it?

Answer (score 0):

i think you could use
delete from account_recharge_detail
where operator_name='fanny-test';
as account_recharge_detail_id is primary key
it can not be null

Comment: I try it! but it returns:Error Code: 1175. You are using safe update mode and you tried to update a table without a WHERE that uses a KEY column To disable safe mode, toggle the option in Preferences -> SQL Editor -> Query Editor and reconnect.

Comment: please refer to sql_safe_updates you could try set sql_safe_updates=0; before execute update sql